# Is paying your bill online more environmentally friendly than post?

Tags: environment

My monthly Comcast statement says that I should go paperless and pay my bill online via "Ecobill, the environmentally friendly way to pay your bill each month".

All jokes about Comcast aside, has anyone done studies about the environmental impact from switching to online bill pay?

Comment: it saves a single person around 3 sheets of paper per bill, ink, electricity to print it and its transport cost (for a few grams)... do the math

Comment: It seems likely that it is more environmentally friendly, since mailing a payment results in practically identical electronic resource utilization--it just happens after the check is received rather than in lieu of the check.

Comment: @ratchetfreak There's an assumption that epayments create no unique costs of their own, offsetting the obvious savings.

Answer (score 7):

According to Quickbooks.com they conducted a study that reported the following results:

"EChecks help reduce the more than 67.4 million gallons of fuel used and 3.6 million tons of greenhouse gas emissions created by transporting paper checks."

It seems that paying online will not only save you money but will help lower green house emissions.

Source:http://quickbooks.intuit.com/facts-about-electronic-checks/

Comment: I'm not sure Intuit QuickBooks is the best source to use here; that page seems like it's trying to promote paperless payments so that people then buy QuickBooks to keep track of payments. Certainly there's an _incentive_ for bias. And it doesn't address any potential downsides, such as, say, increased pollution from power plants because people have to get online to view their bills.

Comment: Further, "67.4 million gallons of fuel used and 3.6 million tons of greenhouse gas emissions created by transporting paper checks" needs its own citation, and also doesn't prove there's no unknown paper/gas/energy usage by making epayments. I know this seems obtuse, but you have to blame the question for that.